Clarifications on Hurst Exponent Definitions and Persistence Properties
I have a question regarding the Hurst exponent that I hope someone here can help clarify.
It is well known that there are different definitions of the Hurst exponent, but finding clear connections or relationships between these definitions seems to be surprisingly challenging. I’ve come across various interpretations, yet I haven’t found a comprehensive explanation of how these different definitions align or differ in practical applications.
Additionally, it is commonly stated that:

For $H<0.5$ the process exhibits antipersistence.
For $H>0.5$ the process exhibits persistence.

However, while this classification appears frequently, the reasoning or deeper explanation behind it is rarely provided.
Could anyone offer some clarifications, or perhaps point me toward reliable bibliographic references that address:

The relationships between the various definitions of the Hurst exponent.
A clear explanation of why $H<0.5$ corresponds to antipersistence and $H>0.5$ corresponds to persistence.

Thank you in advance for your insights!
